# How to handle different uploaded dimensions pictures and resize them to standard size(dimensions) without losing quality?

Tags: php, iphone, android, ios, gd

For my Iphone and Android App. I allow users to upload images(which can be of different dimensions). These images are later displayed in the app(TableView). How can i assure that the images that are being uploaded by different users will have the same dimensions and quality in the Mobile App?

Comment: By size do you mean image dimensions or file size?

Comment: what if your user uploads a low quality image?

Comment: You can find out the size of the uploaded image dimensions using the GD function getimagesize(); As for quality, I don't know how you will programaticaly discover that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this [Simle Image Class](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) for a long time. It works great (except bmp).

Comment: I assume uploads will be posted to php.

Comment: Funny i'm using the same script.The only problem that i have with this script is different dimensions pictures do not get the same size , but they are resized down based on uploaded dimension.

Comment: There is a method for that. $image->resize($width,$height);